# How can I get the h:graphicImage resource path with JavaServer Faces?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, thumbnails, jsf-2.2

In a JSF 2.2 web page, I display an image with `h:graphicImage` but also need a way to refer to the same image in a `<a href="..." />` link.

```
<a class="thumbnail" href="???/image.png" >
  <h:graphicImage name="image.png" />                         
</a>
```

The image resource is included at

```
WEB-INF
 \-web.xml
resources
 \-image.png 
index.html
```

The run-time path rendered by `h:graphicImage` will look like

`/javax.faces.resource/image.png.html;jsessionid=xxx`

How can I get this resource path path for the image to build a `<a href="???/image.png">` element which links to this image?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used

Comment: @kolossus I edited the question, no subfolders of `resources` are involved

Comment: See "Referencing in EL" in dupe.